# Get-DHCPv4Lease Permission denied when run in psexec

Tags: powershell, psexec

I have a script which exports currently console users on a computer list (about 1000 clients). When I run it from my computer it takes about 10 hours to complete because of launching psexec on each client further in the script.
To reduce execution time, I'd like to run parts of this script on about 50 WIndows 2012 (non R2) servers.
Everything works fine when I test through Powershell ISE, Powershell shell and cmd shell. But when I launch it from my computer with elevated command prompt using psexec for the following command line

```
ForEach ( $file in Get-content c:\it\exports_generic\dhcp_scopes.txt ) {Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName "srv-frad3.domain.local" -ScopeId  10.10.29.0 | Where{$_.AddressState -eq "Active" -and $_.Hostname -match "GCC|TPT|ATM|DIS"} | Select-Object Hostname | findstr domain.local | Out-File c:\it\exports_generic\10.10.29.0.txt}
```

I get the following error :

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease : Failed to get scope information for scope 10.10.29.0 on DHCP 
server srv-frad3.domain.local.
At C:\it\extrac_generic\script.ps1:10 char:57
+ ForEach ( $file in Get-content $path\dhcp_scopes.txt ) {Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -C ...
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (10.10.29.0:root/Microsoft/...cpServerv4Lease) 
[Get-DhcpServerv4Lease]
   , CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 5,Get-DhcpServerv4Lease
```

I run my psexec with the same credentials used for test on ISE and shells, so I can't understand why it shouldn't work by using psexec  (have tried psexec -h too, but no more luck)

Has anyone an idea about this troubleshoot ?

Comment: What is the value of `$path` and `$file` at the time of the failure? You can [edit] your question to include this information.  You should modify the script accordingly to print the value if it encounters an error.

Comment: How large are your DHCP scopes? Ten hours seems a bit surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for replies

Finally I deploied a new schedule task on each server and launch it on demand via schtasks. No problem using this way.